# Accessing the zip file and folder in S3 from EC2 instance using boto3 package in Python

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services

I got an issue, i want to look inside a zip File that i will drop on my bucket, it has this structure:

main.zip ==>main/folder1/subfolder/file.xml ==>main/dolfer2/file.xml

Using a lambda function i need to swim on the zip file capturate del path from xmls files then parse them with xml.dom.minidom

I am doing this:

```
key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
bucket = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'].encode('utf8'))
    try:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:
        # rewind the file
        tf.seek(0)
        # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:  
            for file in zipf.infolist():
                fileName = file.filename
                putFile = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key='Open/'+fileName, Body=zipf.read(file))
                print(putFile)
```

how can i go over all the zip and capturate the path/object of the xmls file on the zip(even if they are inside any folder on the zip) to parse the xml with xml.dom.minidom?

I got to go over en folder and got de xml file on it with:
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import os
import boto3

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    s3= boto3.client('s3')
    datos = []
    if event:
        print('event:',event)
        file_obj = event['Records'][0]
        filename = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
        print('filename',filename)
        fileobj = s3.get_object(Bucket='mi-informacion-audit',Key=filename)
        file_content = fileobj[y]['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        #print(file_content)
        datos.append(file_content.replace('\n',''))
    for x in range(len(datos)):
        print(datos[x])
        doc = parseString(datos[x])
        nodeListCom = doc.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Comprobante')
        for x in range(len(nodeListCom)):
            pk_xmlyear = nodeListCom[x].getAttribute('Fecha')[2:4]
            print(pk_xmlyear)
    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

But this folder contains 10 xml file and my code only reads the first one... any help?

Comment: What is the question? What is not working? Include all error messages.

Comment: Could you please narrow-down the specific bit of code that is causing you problems? It appears that this is an AWS Lambda function triggered by the creation of an object in Amazon S3, but that is irrelevant if issue is related to Zip manipulation.

Comment: i update question and i didnt get  error jet, looking for some help with it

Comment: How big is the zip file? Recommendation, break out the zip processing from Lambda as a function. You can then add the Lambda front end to call your function. This way you can test on your desktop first.

Comment: Next, what is it that you really want to do? You ask about processing an xmls file but you post a code example that processes a zip file and upload each file to S3. Edit your question to be one task at a time. Include code that your wrote and explain what problem you are having.

Comment: El zipFile  is like 1.58GB (between folder and xmls files only). I got the process that unZip de "zip", but i was wondering if while i am puting on the directory of the bucket as the code up lines i could go over the xmls file and use xml.dom.minidom parse to manage them

Comment: The first step is to think thru your problem and verify service constraints. The largest Lambda function is 3008 MB of memory. This will allow the zip file to fit into memory compressed. Next is bandwidth. A good design will achieve 10 MB / sec. This will take 158 seconds at best and could take as much as 1,580 seconds at worst (1 MB / sec) - FAIL. The max run time for Lambda is 300 seconds. You definitely cannot download a zip file, parse it and upload individual files to S3. Now, I do not know if the zip library that you are using will support zip files this big in memory.

Comment: Didnt know about that, now, if i drag the unzip i could do a lambda function that go over de folder from that bucket and catch the xmls file  and then parse to xml.dom.minidom, bytheway if i do this:
full_path = "s3://"+self.bucket+"/"+ruta
doc = minidom.parse(full_path)
doesnt work, even if a do with 
urlpath = 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile'
r = requests.get(urlpath)